# Flutter - How to call this function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have something like that, I tried so many ways and can't call the function like I want.

```
class PageTest extends StatefulWidget {
  PageTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageTest> createState() => PageTestState();
}

class PageTestState extends State<PageTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: topMyBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [PageTestList()],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: floatingButton(),
    );
  }

  Widget floatingButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
      onPressed: () {
        CALL pageTestListFunction() AND SETSTATE ON _PageTestListState;
      },
      backgroundColor: AppColors.status_ready,
      label: Text(
        'OK',
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
      ));
  }
}

-- END HERE --

class PageTestList extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTestList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageTestList> createState() => _PageTestListState();
}

class _PageTestListState extends State<PageTestList> {...
  Future<bool> pageTestListFunction() async {...}
}
```

Is there a way to call the function from PageTestList when onPressed on floatingActionButton is called and then setState on PageTestList?

Thank's!

Comment: PageTestList is a widget so here you can show widget inside the bottom sheet whenever floating action button clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global key in your widget.

```
class PageTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageTest> createState() => PageTestState();
}

class PageTestState extends State<PageTest> {
  final _globalkey = GlobalKey<PageTestListState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: topMyBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [PageTestList(key:_globalkey)],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: floatingButton(),
    );
  }

  Widget floatingButton() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          //CALL pageTestListFunction() AND SETSTATE ON _PageTestListState;
          _globalkey.currentState?.pageTestListFunction();
        },
        backgroundColor: AppColors.status_ready,
        label: const Text(
          'OK',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
        ));
  }
}


class PageTestList extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTestList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<PageTestList> createState() => PageTestListState();
}

class PageTestListState extends State<PageTestList> {
  var color = Colors.red;
  void pageTestListFunction() async {
    setState(() {
      color = Colors.green;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that PageTest + PageTestState are in a file "pageTest.dart" and PageTestList + _PageTestListState are in a file "pageTestList.dart".
When I try to "final _globalkey = GlobalKey<_PageTestListState>();" I got the errors:

The name '_PageTestListState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named '_PageTestListState'.

'dynamic' doesn't conform to the bound 'State<StatefulWidget>' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'State<StatefulWidget>'.

Comment: So you would have to make your _PageTestListState public, just remove the `_`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank's for this mate <3